# Obtaining a summary of grouped counts in R

Tags: r, dplyr

This should be simple but I have been stumped by it: I am trying to figure out an efficient method for obtaining summary stats of a grouped count. Here's a toy example:

```
df = tibble(pid = c(1,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,4), y = rnorm(10))
df %>% group_by(pid) %>% count(pid)
```

which outputs the expected

```
# A tibble: 4 × 2
# Groups:   pid [4]
    pid     n
  <dbl> <int>
1     1     1
2     2     2
3     3     3
4     4     4
```

However, what if I want a summary of those grouped counts? Attempting to mutate a new variable or add_count hasn't worked I assume because the variables are different sizes. For instance:

```
df %>% group_by(pid) %>% count(pid) %>% mutate(count = summary(n))
```

generates an error. What would be a simple way to generate summary statistics of the grouped counts (e.g., min, max, mean, etc.)?

Comment: What exactly is the desired output here? Are you expecting a data frame with just one row and different columns for min, max, mean etc?

Comment: Maybe you want `df %>% group_by(pid) %>% count(pid) %>% pull(n) %>% summary()`?

Comment: @MrFlick that would suffice. this is for data exploration purposes and I just want to gain a sense of how many times IDs are replicated in large datasets

Comment: @GregorThomas that is perfect! Pull was what I needed, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`mutate` is for adding columns to a data frame - you don't want that here, you need to pull the column out of the data frame.

```
df %>% 
  count(pid) %>% 
  pull(n) %>% 
  summary()
```